# How to show actual HTML and CSS markups in browsers

Tags: markup

```
<p> Attribute <span style="color: #EFEFEF"> <accept> </span>
- Specifies the types of files that the server accepts (only for type="file") </p>
```

I want to see actual HTML & CSS markups in browsers not its rendered version. How can I accomplish that ?

We can see it often on tutoring websites

Comment: [pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

Comment: It didn't work with that  <pre><p> Note: The <input> element is empty, it contains attributes only.  Tip: Use the <' label '> element to define labels for <input> elements.
</p> </pre>

Comment: <input> shows me a blank space and <p> tag isn't shown . I see a text instead

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. `pre` just retains some formatting. It's best to enclose the markup in the semantic `code` block as well, and you'll have to escape the HTML so that `<` and `>` become `&lt;` and `&gt;`. See http://www.sitepoint.com/everything-need-know-html-pre-element/

Comment: <pre> </pre> is not working for CSS markup can you suggest anything

Comment: Ehrm, didn’t you do just that in this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually my solution is `xmp` tag for HTML markups